# What's the difference between new Uri(..) and new UriBuilder(..).Uri for the same host?

Tags: .net, uri, wif, uribuilder

In a web application, I have an audienceURI used for the authentication. When I set it from code like the following:

```
var audience1 = new UriBuilder("dev.website.com")
                 {
                    Port = 443,
                    Scheme = "https",
                    Path = "/"
                 }.Uri; // Does not work!
```

It is not wokring.

But when I set it like this:

```
var audenice2 = new Uri("https://dev.website.com"); // It works!
```

it works fine.

The funny thing is that the following is working fine !!

```
var audience3 = new Uri(audience1.ToString());  // It works!
```

Any idea what's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

The `UriBuilder` (like any implementation of the builder pattern) allows you to provide the pieces needed to assemble a larger object in 'piecemeal' fashion, and then allowing you to generate an instance of the final product (using the `.Uri` property). You don't necessarily need to build the object in one go (i.e. you can mutate a builder as you go along).

However, it seems you aren't using the `UriBuilder(String)` constructor correctly. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y868d5wh(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This constructor initializes a new instance of the UriBuilder class with the Fragment, Host, Path, Port, Query, Scheme, and Uri properties set as specified in uri.

Meaning you would need to do this to use this constructor overload:

```
 var audience1 = new UriBuilder("https://dev.website.com").Uri;
```

(or even `https://dev.website.com:443`)

Which wouldn't be useful to you as it has no benefit over constructing a `Uri` directly with the same string.

The `UriBuilder` would more typically be used to piece-meal assemble the Uri, like so:

```
var myUriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
myUriBuilder.Host = (host == "dev")
  ? "dev.website.com"
  : "qa.website.com";

 if (useSsl)
 {
     myUriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
     myUriBuilder.Port = 443;
 }

var myUri = myUriBuilder.Uri;
```

(i.e. with somewhat complex logic determining the fate of each of the builder's properties in separate statements).

Comment: Actually it did not work. If I changed the port to be -1, it works fine !

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "doesn't work" - all techniques (direct `Uri` and `UriBuilder`, and piecemeal `UriBuilder`) can be used to build the same Uri's? Setting Port to -1 resets the Uri to its default port based on scheme (e.g. 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS)